# Python sort and merge with dense list of sublisted lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, merge, duplicates

A dense list matrix is comprised of something along the following: list-of sublists-of tuple lists.

Where for sake of simplicity - just the first 'sublist of tuple lists' will be discussed:

```
[[[(390,200),(380,206)],[(381,203),(368,209)],[(359,204),(343,211)],
[(308,197),(284,203)],[(331,196),(303,201)],[(359,196),(351,198)],
[(381,197),(377,203)],[(380,206),(365,213)],[(368,209),(352,215)],
[(343,211),(325,217)],[(284,203),(264,209)],[(303,201),(281,207)],
[(351,198),(322,201)], [(377,203),(364,210)]],...
```

What is needed, is the (preferred in place) sorting and merging based on the first and last indexes of each tuple list of (x,y) coordinates; essentially creating contiguous line segments from segment pairs.

Ideally, and output of the above would be expressed as:

```
[[[(390,200),(380,206),(380,206),(365,213)],[(381,203),(368,209),(368,209),
(352,215)],[(359,204),(343,211),(343,211),(325,217)],[(308,197),(284,203),
(284,203),(264,209)],[(331,196),(303,201),(303,201),(281,207)],[(359,196),
(351,198),(351,198),(322,201)],[(381,197),(377,203),(377,203),
(364,210)]],...
```

... and subsequently all duplicates after sort and merge would be reduced ...

```
[[[(390,200),(380,206),(365,213)],[(381,203),(368,209),(352,215)],
[(359,204),(343,211),(325,217)],[(308,197),(284,203),(264,209)],[(331,196),
(303,201),(281,207)],[(359,196),(351,198),(322,201)],[(381,197),(377,203),
(364,210)]],...
```

Having tried creating duplicate lists, and using loops really didn't come close to what seems like would be a relatively simple sort and merge (for someone more advanced than I).

***UPDATE:***

Oversimplification of input data (above) might make a solution simpler than needed - so the following is complete representation of the matrices:

```
[[(443390,4.362e+06), (443390,4.362e+06), (443388,4.36202e+06), 
(443385,4.36204e+06), (443381,4.36206e+06), (443380,4.36206e+06)], 
[(443381,4.36203e+06), (443379,4.36204e+06), (443377,4.36205e+06), 
(443375,4.36206e+06), (443370,4.36208e+06), (443368,4.36209e+06)], 
[(443359,4.36204e+06), (443357,4.36205e+06), (443354,4.36206e+06), 
(443349,4.36208e+06), (443344,4.3621e+06), (443343,4.36211e+06)], 
[(443308,4.36197e+06), (443305,4.36198e+06), (443297,4.362e+06), 
(443295,4.362e+06), (443287,4.36202e+06), (443284,4.36203e+06)], 
[(443331,4.36196e+06), (443329,4.36196e+06), (443317,4.36198e+06), 
(443317,4.36198e+06), (443305,4.362e+06), (443303,4.36201e+06)], 
[(443359,4.36196e+06), (443357,4.36196e+06), (443357,4.36196e+06), 
(443351,4.36198e+06)], [(443381,4.36197e+06), (443380,4.36198e+06), 
(443380,4.362e+06), (443379,4.36202e+06), (443377,4.36203e+06)], 
[(443380,4.36206e+06), (443377,4.36208e+06), (443376,4.36208e+06), 
(443371,4.3621e+06), (443366,4.36212e+06), (443365,4.36213e+06)], 
[(443368,4.36209e+06), (443365,4.3621e+06), (443360,4.36212e+06), 
(443357,4.36213e+06), (443354,4.36214e+06), (443352,4.36215e+06)], 
[(443343,4.36211e+06), (443339,4.36212e+06), (443337,4.36213e+06), 
(443333,4.36214e+06), (443327,4.36216e+06), (443325,4.36217e+06)], 
[(443284,4.36203e+06), (443281,4.36204e+06), (443277,4.36205e+06), 
(443274,4.36206e+06), (443267,4.36208e+06), (443264,4.36209e+06)], 
[(443303,4.36201e+06), (443297,4.36202e+06), (443297,4.36202e+06), 
(443291,4.36204e+06), (443284,4.36206e+06), (443281,4.36207e+06)], 
[(443351,4.36198e+06), (443348,4.36198e+06), (443337,4.36199e+06), 
(443327,4.362e+06), (443322,4.36201e+06)], [(443377,4.36203e+06), 
(443377,4.36203e+06), (443376,4.36204e+06), (443372,4.36206e+06), 
(443367,4.36208e+06), (443364,4.3621e+06)]],...
```

***Further Updates:***
Martijn Peters provided direction which presumably is the answer, but allocating actual values for the coordinates and not just the condensed display values expresses comparisons must be more involved ( I suppose? ).

The following commands:

```
pathGroup = [[(443390,4.362e+06), (443390,4.362e+06), (443388,4.36202e+06), 
(443385,4.36204e+06), (443381,4.36206e+06), (443380,4.36206e+06)], 
[(443381,4.36203e+06), (443379,4.36204e+06), (443377,4.36205e+06), 
(443375,4.36206e+06), (443370,4.36208e+06), (443368,4.36209e+06)], 
[(443359,4.36204e+06), (443357,4.36205e+06), (443354,4.36206e+06), 
(443349,4.36208e+06), (443344,4.3621e+06), (443343,4.36211e+06)], 
[(443308,4.36197e+06), (443305,4.36198e+06), (443297,4.362e+06), 
(443295,4.362e+06), (443287,4.36202e+06), (443284,4.36203e+06)], 
[(443331,4.36196e+06), (443329,4.36196e+06), (443317,4.36198e+06), 
(443317,4.36198e+06), (443305,4.362e+06), (443303,4.36201e+06)], 
[(443359,4.36196e+06), (443357,4.36196e+06), (443357,4.36196e+06), 
(443351,4.36198e+06)], [(443381,4.36197e+06), (443380,4.36198e+06), 
(443380,4.362e+06), (443379,4.36202e+06), (443377,4.36203e+06)], 
[(443380,4.36206e+06), (443377,4.36208e+06), (443376,4.36208e+06), 
(443371,4.3621e+06), (443366,4.36212e+06), (443365,4.36213e+06)], 
[(443368,4.36209e+06), (443365,4.3621e+06), (443360,4.36212e+06), 
(443357,4.36213e+06), (443354,4.36214e+06), (443352,4.36215e+06)], 
[(443343,4.36211e+06), (443339,4.36212e+06), (443337,4.36213e+06), 
(443333,4.36214e+06), (443327,4.36216e+06), (443325,4.36217e+06)], 
[(443284,4.36203e+06), (443281,4.36204e+06), (443277,4.36205e+06), 
(443274,4.36206e+06), (443267,4.36208e+06), (443264,4.36209e+06)], 
[(443303,4.36201e+06), (443297,4.36202e+06), (443297,4.36202e+06), 
(443291,4.36204e+06), (443284,4.36206e+06), (443281,4.36207e+06)], 
[(443351,4.36198e+06), (443348,4.36198e+06), (443337,4.36199e+06), 
(443327,4.362e+06), (443322,4.36201e+06)], [(443377,4.36203e+06), 
(443377,4.36203e+06), (443376,4.36204e+06), (443372,4.36206e+06), 
(443367,4.36208e+06), (443364,4.3621e+06)]]
new = [self.sorted_and_merged(tupList) for tupList in pathGroup]
print new

#...from outside method sorted_and_merged()...
return [t for t in sorted(tuplelist) if not (t[0], format(t[1], '.3e'))
        in seen or seen_add((t[0], format(t[1], '.3e')))]
```

results in:

```
[[(443380,4.36206e+06), (443381,4.36206e+06), (443385,4.36204e+06), 
(443388,4.36202e+06), (443390,4.362e+06), (443390,4.362e+06)], 
[(443368,4.36209e+06), (443370,4.36208e+06), (443375,4.36206e+06), 
(443377,4.36205e+06), (443379,4.36204e+06), (443381,4.36203e+06)], 
[(443343,4.36211e+06), (443344,4.3621e+06), (443349,4.36208e+06), 
(443354,4.36206e+06), (443357,4.36205e+06), (443359,4.36204e+06)], 
[(443284,4.36203e+06), (443287,4.36202e+06), (443295,4.362e+06), 
(443297,4.362e+06), (443305,4.36198e+06), (443308,4.36197e+06)], 
[(443303,4.36201e+06), (443305,4.362e+06), (443317,4.36198e+06), 
(443317,4.36198e+06), (443329,4.36196e+06), (443331,4.36196e+06)], 
[(443351,4.36198e+06), (443357,4.36196e+06), (443357,4.36196e+06), 
(443359,4.36196e+06)], [(443377,4.36203e+06), (443379,4.36202e+06), 
(443380,4.362e+06), (443380,4.36198e+06), (443381,4.36197e+06)], 
[(443365,4.36213e+06), (443366,4.36212e+06), (443371,4.3621e+06), 
(443376,4.36208e+06), (443377,4.36208e+06), (443380,4.36206e+06)], 
[(443352,4.36215e+06), (443354,4.36214e+06), (443357,4.36213e+06), 
(443360,4.36212e+06), (443365,4.3621e+06), (443368,4.36209e+06)], 
[(443325,4.36217e+06), (443327,4.36216e+06), (443333,4.36214e+06), 
(443337,4.36213e+06), (443339,4.36212e+06), (443343,4.36211e+06)], 
[(443264,4.36209e+06), (443267,4.36208e+06), (443274,4.36206e+06), 
(443277,4.36205e+06), (443281,4.36204e+06), (443284,4.36203e+06)], 
[(443281,4.36207e+06), (443284,4.36206e+06), (443291,4.36204e+06), 
(443297,4.36202e+06), (443297,4.36202e+06), (443303,4.36201e+06)], 
[(443322,4.36201e+06), (443327,4.362e+06), (443337,4.36199e+06), 
(443348,4.36198e+06), (443351,4.36198e+06)], [(443364,4.3621e+06), 
(443367,4.36208e+06), (443372,4.36206e+06), (443376,4.36204e+06), 
(443377,4.36203e+06), (443377,4.36203e+06)]]
```

It seems some of the sort is misappropriated.

Comment: Is there a cause why you have that in three lists? There is no visible reason of a third level.

Comment: @KlausD.: presumably there are more such nested structures.

Comment: @ Klaus D. : Each third level represents a group which much be made distinct from all other groups, and through other processes be able to be grabbed 'individually' on a whim.  Perhaps there is a more ideal means of accomplishing this requirement - but python experience dictates the current take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a simple sort and merge; using `sorted()` together with [removing duplicates while keeping the list ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order) you'd get:

```
def sorted_and_merged(tuplelist):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [t for t in sorted(tuplelist, reverse=True) if not (t in seen or seen_add(t))]
```

Apply this to each sublist:

```
[sorted_and_merged(sublist) for sublist in completelist]
```

Demo:

```
>>> sample = [[(390,200),(380,206),(380,206),(365,213)],[(381,203),(368,209),(368,209),
... (352,215)],[(359,204),(343,211),(343,211),(325,217)],[(308,197),(284,203),
... (284,203),(264,209)],[(331,196),(303,201),(303,201),(281,207)],[(359,196),
... (351,198),(351,198),(322,201)],[(381,197),(377,203),(377,203),
... (364,210)]]
>>> def sorted_and_merged(tuplelist):
...     seen = set()
...     seen_add = seen.add
...     return [t for t in sorted(tuplelist, reverse=True) if not (t in seen or seen_add(t))]
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([sorted_and_merged(sublist) for sublist in sample])
[[(390, 200), (380, 206), (365, 213)],
 [(381, 203), (368, 209), (352, 215)],
 [(359, 204), (343, 211), (325, 217)],
 [(308, 197), (284, 203), (264, 209)],
 [(331, 196), (303, 201), (281, 207)],
 [(359, 196), (351, 198), (322, 201)],
 [(381, 197), (377, 203), (364, 210)]]
```

Comment: Wow that actually is understandable for my skill level and looks like its the ticket.  However I am getting an odd error - "[self.sorted_and_merged(tupList) for tupList in pathGroup]
TypeError: sorted_and_merged() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)",  where tupList is identical to the 'sample' expressed in your demo.

Comment: @Katalpa: I see you are trying to make it a method instead; in that case you'd need to add the `self` argument. You can make this a nested function however, or a global.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieteres : When used as a method your advice fixed the error.  Yet it seems my simplification of the lists I am using might have skewed results.   With a bit more complicated 'sample' list, this method seems to make no changes.  I will update the original post with the complex list.  Thank you for your clues.

Comment: @Katalpa: that's because you have *floating point values*. Comparing floats frequently results in inequalities as very small differences are possible. You'd need to pick a tolerance level for what makes values equal, then round the values before testing against and adding to the set.

Comment: @ Martijn Peters : Of course, (palms face*).  Floating Points are unfriendly to direct comparisons, and this should have been recognized sooner.  Its clear the tools needed have been shared (thanks), now I just need to finish things off.  Marking your answer as proper - but will update original post with resultant action(s) for solution.

Comment: @Katalpa: search for using floating point numbers as dictionary keys; it is the exact same problem as using them in sets.

Comment: @ Martijn Peters : Would it be conceivable to set tolerance within the sort_and_merged() function in some manner?   The following had no effect - but that is likely because the rounding should take place before even calling said function?    "        return [(float('%.3f'%x),float('%.3f'%y)) for x,y in sorted(tuplelist) \
                if not ((float('%.3f'%x),float('%.3f'%y)) in seen \
                or seen_add((float('%.3f'%x),float('%.3f'%y))))]"

Comment: Your `x` is not a float. Your `y` *is* a float, but **very small**. I'd use the `e` formatting option here instead.

Comment: @Katalpa: Just use `format(y, '.3e')` when storing in and comparing to the set: `if not ((t[0], format(t[1], '.3e'))  in seen or seen_add((t[0], format(t[1], '.3e')))`

Comment: @ Martijn Peters : repr(x,y) reveals that both the X and Y coordinates are quite precise (if I understand correctly).  Updated the original posting to reflect this.

Comment: @Katalpa: you are actually *returning or otherwise using* the output of the list comprehension, right? It produces a **new** list, the old list is not affected.

Comment: @ Martin Peters : Last update to post hopefully reflects that I am analyzing the output from the method as a new item independent from the input list.

Comment: @Katalpa: Your output looks incorrect, as it contains just the one element per tuple. My approach works fine otherwise, I think; see https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/2badd989f9241405c9ff

Comment: @ Martin Peters : matched your gitHub submission : and the results are reflected in revised most recent update to original post - I also have forwarded an important message to you via codementor....